# apache2 помощь в регулярных выражениях

Tags: apache2

Есть конфиг сайта на apache2, как можно сделать чтобы один и тот же параметр выполнялся для нескольких папок, сейчас у меня:

```
<Directory "^/var/www/html/(ini|cache)">
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

но он не работает ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Directory ~ "^/var/www/html/(ini|cache)">
    deny from all
</Directory>
```